# What's a good way to run a command instead of opening a file?

Tags: elisp

I have this code to play mp3 files instead of opening them:

```cl
(defun ora-mp3 ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((file (buffer-file-name)))
    (kill-buffer (current-buffer))
    (ora-dired-start-process (format "rhythmbox \"%s\"" file))))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mp3\\'" . ora-mp3))
```

Here `ora-dired-start-process` is just a variant of `shell-command`.

I kind of like using `auto-mode-alist`, since it's very granular: only
mp3 files are affected. But the problem is that my window
configuration gets messed up each time `ora-mp3` is called.

How could I avoid the problem with the current approach? Or maybe
there's another approach that doesn't have this problem?

Comment: Looks like you want to play the mp3 files from dired? If so you can advice the "dired find file" function (I am not at a computer, so don't know the exact name) with before-until modifier. If the dired-copy-filename-as-kill returns an mp3 file, run ora-dired-start-process, else do the default dired find file.

Comment: This is a situation where using find-file is not really the right approach, use a new command with `(interactive "f")` to grab a file name and just work with that.

Comment: @JordonBiondo, I know that it's iffy. But it works (except the window configuration thing). There are zero instances of when I would want to edit an mp3 file, but some advantages: e.g. I could browse playlists with `find-file-in-project` or something.

Comment: This should be closed as essentially a duplicate of http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3105/105. OP: in any case, see also that question for answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to use the [openwith](http://melpa.org/#/openwith) package which provides a global minor mode that installs a file name handler that consults a customizable list of program associations. Even if you don't like openwith, I think the idea of using [file name handlers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Magic-File-Names.html) is a good one.

openwith has the advantage of working everywhere you open a file, but also has the disadvantage of working everywhere Emacs implicitly opens a file for you! In particular I remember being annoyed that grepping across a directory in dired would open my PDFs in an external viewer and play my videos! I remember whipping up something to put in my `init.el` to counteract that, maybe advising some dired function to deactivate `openwith-mode` first, something like that. At any rate it was easy to workaround.

I stopped using openwith when I started using Helm, as I find typing `C-c C-x` from `helm-find-files` convenient enough. (Also nowadays, I only unconditionally open audio and video files outside of Emacs, so most of the time I like being able to either open a file in Emacs or in an external program.)

Answer (score 1):

I use <kbd>! open RET</kbd> in `dired` buffer which DTRT for all files like `mp3`, `odt` &c.

Comment: Thanks, I already bound "r" in `dired` to do that years ago. My interest is in making it work everywhere, for example from a `locate` or a `find-file` completion session, or from a bookmark etc.